# How do I change the color of a checkbox without changing it for the whole class?

Tags: html, css

I need to change the style of a checkbox label.

this is my html:

```
<div class="ui-checkbox">
  <input id="keepMeInformed" type="checkbox" data-theme="d" onchange="fixCheckboxesValues();" checked="checked" value="1" name="optedIn">
    <label class="optional ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-d ui-checkbox-off" for="keepMeInformed" data-theme="d">
      <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all" aria-hidden="true">
         <span class="ui-btn-text">Label text</span>
         <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-checkbox-off"></span>
       </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

I need the text to be red but if I change the .ui-btn-text class style all the buttons of the page will get the red text style.

```
.ui-btn-text{
    color:red;
}
```

Is there a way to change only the color of the label in the checkbox?

**Edit**:

thanks guys I solved the problem adding a div that wrapped the CheckBox and wrote jQuery:

```
function changeCheckBoxStyle() { 
   $('#checkBoxWrapper').find('[class=ui-btn-text]').css('color','red');
 }
```

but I think that scott's solution works ok too :) thanks

Comment: hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code. have you tried to be more specific in your selectors, like `.ui-checkbox .ui-btn .ui-bttn-inner .ui-btn-text { color:red; }`?

Comment: or you could just make a new class `.ui-btn-text-red` which basically has all the same properties as `.ui-btn-text` as well as `color:red`? Or if it's just that one button, why not just give it an `id` in the HTML and do a corresponding css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using ID's correctly (unique to a page) then this should work:

```
#keepMeInformed + label .ui-btn-text {
    color: red;
}
```

It looks for the unique `input` element `keepMeInformed` and then finds the sibling `label` element next to it and applies the style to that label's `.ui-btn-text` class element only.

Comment: thanks guys I solved the problem adding a div that wrapped the CheckBox and wrote  jQuery:

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeCheckBoxStyle() { 
        $('#checkBoxWrapper').find('[class=ui-btn-text]').css('color','red');
    </script>

but I think that scott's solution works ok too :) thanks